# Apply function on python data frame - on each cell on a specific column, by other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have this df -

```
sentence        idx 
a b c           1
d k t           0
```

and I want to add a tag to each sentence on the idx word,

```
sentence        
a <ref>b</ref> c          
<ref>d</ref> k t
```

means I want to apply some function on each cell on column "sentence", with the information that is in another column - "idx".

for example with this function:

```
def add_tags_to_sentence(sentence, idx):
    split_sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    split_sentence[idx] = "<ref>" + split_sentence[idx] + "</ref>"
    return " ".join(split_sentence)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
def add_tags_to_sentence(inp):
    inp = inp.values
    sentence = inp[0]
    idx = inp[1]
    split_sentence = sentence.split(' ')
    split_sentence[idx] = "<ref>" + split_sentence[idx] + "</ref>"
    return " ".join(split_sentence)
```

Then use it with `apply` with `axis=1`

```
df['sentence'] = df[['sentence','idx']].apply(add_tags_to_sentence,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "sentence" : ['a b c', 'd k t'],
    "idx"      : [1,0]
})
```

df:

```
  sentence  idx
0    a b c    1
1    d k t    0
```

```
def fun(x):
    x1 = x.sentence.split()
    x2 = "<ref>" + x1[x['idx']] + "</ref>"
    x1[x['idx']] = x2
    return ' '.join(x1)
df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

```
0    a <ref>b</ref> c
1    <ref>d</ref> k t
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Any function can be applied using `dataFrame_name[column].apply(func_name)` function, where columns is the one you want to apply the function to.
NOTE: func_name in `.apply()` does not have brackets at its end.